# serverless.yml Output exports does not work as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

All of my exports in the serverless files are not setting the export values in cloudformation.

As an example, I have the following section in one of my serverless.yml files:

```
Outputs:
  UserPoolName:
    Value: ${self:custom.userPoolName}
    Export:
      Name:  ${self:custom.stage}-userPoolName
```

But when I try to access it with

```
pool: 
  'Fn::ImportValue': ${self:custom.stage}-userPoolName
```

it says:

> 'user-service-dev - No export named dev-userPoolName found.'

And I checked the exports section in the cloud formation console and its empty. This is same for the other serverless files as well.

Another export I have is

```
Outputs:
  UserTableArn:
    Value:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - UserTable
        - Arn
    Export:
      Name: ${self:custom.stage}-userTableArn
```

This value is also not available. What have I done incorrectly here?

Comment: Are you trying to import a value from the same stack?

Comment: No, These are on different stacks

Comment: Can you see the named outputs on the stack in the AWS CloudFormation console?

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help me guys. FInally figured that I had done silly embarrassing mistake, The issue was an indentation error. instead of adding Outputs under resources section i had put it as a separate section. :'(